# I'm trying to make a cursor in MySQL with MAMP server

Tags: mysql, apache, cursor, wamp, mamp

I'm create the procedure but i get this error #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

```
create procedure cursor1()
BEGIN
   declare cel integer;
   declare cur1 cursor for select Usu_Id from Usu_Registro;

   open cur1;
       read_loop: LOOP
           fetch cur1 INTO cel;
           select cel;
       End LOOP;
   close cur1;
END;
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: im create the procedure but when im try to execute i get this error #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a copy paste issue, but why is there an hanging '

Comment: what do you mean whit hanging ? umm no i put them there because for separate code from text, was a mistake  thanks

Comment: Use a different delimiter

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but the problem its SELECT cel; inside the procedure, im test them using INSERT and work. I dont know why but work for me